# Rails. Create an object with its association in one transaction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create an object with the associated item all in the step of creation.
Although I have tried creating first, and then second, this gives problems in the way that if the second fails, then I get with the first part half done.

- Relationship one user has many companies

I mean something like

```
  user = User.create!(
    email: prospect.email,
    first_name: prospect.first_name,
    last_name: prospect.last_name,
    #birthdate:prospect.user_birthday,
    id_number: prospect.id_number,
    phone: prospect.phone,
    address: prospect.address,
    password: prospect.id_number,
    password_confirmation: prospect.id_number,
    company = user.companies.create(
      name: prospect.vat_company_name,
      plan: prospect.plan,
      address: prospect.address,
      description: prospect.company_description,
      email: prospect.email,
      phone: prospect.phone,
      network_id: prospect.network_id
    )
    current_company_id: company.id
  )
```

which of course fails because maybe it can't be done directly.

I have tried build instead of create, but same result.

I also know that second create will fail because the first object doesn't exist yet.

How is the best way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create them both separately and wrap them in a [transaction](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Transactions/ClassMethods.html):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
  user = User.create!(...)
  company = Company.create!(...)
end
```

This way if one of them fails, the other doesn't end up being committed to the database.

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about separate instance storage then using a db transaction lock is the way to go forward as mentioned by Danial. But if you only need to create an associated record of active record then you can do with Active Record only. It would make sure that both records are saved.

```
   user = User.new
    email: prospect.email,
    first_name: prospect.first_name,
    last_name: prospect.last_name,
    #birthdate:prospect.user_birthday,
    id_number: prospect.id_number,
    phone: prospect.phone,
    address: prospect.address,
    password: prospect.id_number,
    password_confirmation: prospect.id_number

  user.build_current_company
      name: prospect.vat_company_name,
      plan: prospect.plan,
      address: prospect.address,
      description: prospect.company_description,
      email: prospect.email,
      phone: prospect.phone,
      network_id: prospect.network_id

   user.save!
```

This will create both user and it's current company.
(I am taking an assumption that you have `belongs_to :current_company,class_name: 'Company'` in `user.rb`)

Comment: Thanks! That works fine too. And it is a valid solution.